# Override nodejs package

Tags: node.js, docker, node-modules

This is perhaps a newbie question. I have modified an opensource node package "A", how do I use this in place of the original open source package "A". I can do this during local development by merely adding the local package reference using npm i, but in production using docker, how do I reference this package ?

1. Is there a cleaner way than copying the package into the local docker build directory using a script and running the docker build after that>
2. The node overrides option seems to only work for secondary dependencies not direct dependencies. Is my assumption correct

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's now your custom code and is not available via NPM or any other packager.  So, you have to either make it available via a packager where it can be downloaded as part of the installation using you package.json or you have to make its code part of your project.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, the package is currently published as @b/A .how do I publish it and ensure its imported into my package.. coz right now all referenced imports are referenced as @b/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solutions was simpler than i thought,
@jfriend suggestion was perfect

I just added the new package as an alias of the old package and it works well. Refer to the below link:

[Yarn packages installation reference](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add)

In my case package A could be replaced by package B by merely
yarn add A@npm:B